# How can I run many C++ source files in one CLion project?

Tags: c++, clion

I am using CLion as an IDE. When I create a project a main.cpp is automatically added. I would like to add 30-40 cpp files in a project and keep them as one project. Basically, I just wanna create many .cpp files in one folder and make CLion run them. I can do this in Pycharm by simply creating a project and add as many .py files as I want. But when I want to do this on CLion I got an error. Is it possible to add many .cpp files in a project in CLion, if yes, how can I do that?
An error could be seen in the below. I  added a second.cpp to the project and run and this error message appears.

====================[ Build | trial | Debug ]===================================

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/mertsaner/CLionProjects/trial/cmake-build-debug --target trial -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target trial
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/trial.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/trial.dir/second.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable trial
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/trial.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/trial.dir/second.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [trial] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/trial.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/trial.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [trial] Error 2
```

Comment: Python and C++ languages are totally different languages. C++ has different build systems, Clion use CMake, so you have to see how to use Cmake, for your own needs.

Comment: seems like you have 2 main functions from CMake logs.

Comment: @Yes, each cpp file has its own main function. I would like to run them, just like they are separate projects or just like i run them on command line

Comment: that's what the logs are telling, in C++ you can only have one `main` Function.

Comment: I have not used Clion personally, nor CMake, for this need. But for this I would really use simpler VSCode.

Comment: It is better if you include the Cmake file so that someone can help you.

Comment: @foragerDev, I see your point what this is heading to, but my point is, couldn't edit my files by using IDE as an editor and run them like in the command line/or like they are standalone projects. So my main question is must I create a separate project for each .cpp file?

Comment: cant say anything, I guess yes, you have to create multiple projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clion uses Cmake. If you want to create multiple executable files for eg with names (ex1.cpp, ex2.cpp. ex3.cpp) in one directory, you will do something like this in the CMake file of your directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(some_project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(executable1 ex1.cpp)
add_executable(executable2 ex2.cpp)
add_executable(executable3 ex3.cpp)
```

and so on..

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much! Now I can select any executable I want to use and I can make as many .cpp files as I want within one directory